# Establishing session in etherpad

Tags: etherpad

I can not figure out how can i pass session credentials to and etherpad pad. I always get a message from the etherpad pad like "You do not have permission to access this pad"
Everything i do is according to http://etherpad.org/doc/v1.5.1/#index_example_1 and i can not figure out how can i start a session for a user, having done all the previous steps successfully of the example 1 in the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a set a cookie with the key `sessionID` and the value containing the sessionID received by the `createSession` api.

To test this, I created the cookie using chrome developer tools by running the following in the console:

`document.cookie="sessionID=s.XXXX"`

After this I was able to access the pad located at `/p/g.fcXsYTpiNlJMwX35$samplePad`. *Your padID will be different.*